# Xlsxwriter, how to increase decimal precision of float number?

Tags: python, excel, xlsxwriter

I have created this kind of float format for cells:

```
floating_point_bordered = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0', 'border': 1})

worksheet.write(f'G{row}', position.price, floating_point_bordered)
```

When I generate xlsx file the I got this following result:

[image: Image one]

However the real value of this float is:

[image: Image two]

How to force float cells to show their values if increased precision?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XlsxWriter uses Excel's numeric formats so you should figure out the format you need in Excel first.

It is probably something like `#,##0.00`. For example:

```py
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("test.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

price = 879.65421

floating_point_bordered = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00', 'border': 1})

worksheet.write(2, 1, price, floating_point_bordered)

workbook.close()
```

**Output**:
[image]

However, the numeric format needs to be in the US locale with "grouping/thousands" separator is "," and the "decimal" point is "." (dot). See this section of the XlsxWriter docs on [Number Formats in different locales](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html#number-formats-in-different-locales) for more information.